# Is there a function in the F# standard library to generate a constant function?

Tags: f#, standard-library

I.e., is there a function like this in the standard library?

```
let ret x _ = x
```

To keep code readable, I'd like to minimize the number of home-brew basic building functional building blocks and use stuff that exists instead.

Comment: let (<!) x _ = x // declaring it as operator is looking like more fun. Just thoughts

Comment: Just interesting : How do you use it ?

Comment: That's a good question, and *of course* I remember why... it was just 3 days ago... ehh... :-)

Comment: Roughly though, I was trying to write a List.map expression via function composition, i.e. to avoid the lambda syntax `(fun _-> x)` which I find less readable in large expressions.  e.g. to zip a list with a constant to later be able to map that list of tuples.

Comment: Suggestion for that language feature is here: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/8065539-add-a-function-to-return-a-constant-value           You can vote for it if you want it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You may want to look at FSharpX.

Comment: I'd name it `ignoreRight` (and `ignoreLeft` being K*, or `flip ignoreRight`), but it still might help Eamon.

Comment: @RamonSnir : the name comes from Haskell's `const`

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I know the origin and I know it also fits nicely with the K combinator, but I think it doesn't reflect what it does.

Comment: @RamonSnir: I know very little about SKI calculus, again I invite you to drop by http://groups.google.com/group/fsharpx and help us ;)

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Yeah, I probably should drop by sometime soon. That library I told you about (I think on FPish) is getting quite big, and would be a shame if it will be kept private.

Answer (score 3):

[`konst` in FSharpPlus/Operators.fs](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/600f538b4caef97f3159094cb0e34b2215871fef/src/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L18)

Thanks to the pointer from @user29439 in the comments.